# How to ensure that a timer task to run for a specific JVM in shared environment. Is there any way?

Tags: java, jvm

We have something that runs on a single JVM currently.

We are moving to a shared environment where multiple JVMs are running on the same host.

We want a timer task to be run on a single JVM only. How can we restrict the timer to only run on a single JVM?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tag your JVM instance differently either statically (at launch time) by passing special parameter  or dynamically by using some sort of service registry and master election tools (zookeeper for example) and then in side your application you can modify the code to look for that special marker and decide weather to schedule job or whether to run schedule job or skip it based on state of instance